# 'An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal' by iterating a map

Tags: debugging, dictionary, exception, stl

I am trying to iterate a map with a string as key and a pointer to 'Drug' as a value, and when I initialize the iterator of the map, when I'm debugging I get question marks on the value of 'it', and when I continue, the debugger points at the row of the 'for' loop and shows the exception given above...

```
map<string, Drug *>::iterator it = patient->getDrugs().begin();
for (it; it != patient->getDrugs().end(); it++)
  cout << "Drug ID: " << it->first << " Drug name: " << it->second->getName() << endl;
```

how can I solve the problem (To be able to iterate the map)?

Comment: Does `patient->getDrugs()` return by value, by any chance? I suspect it does, in which case a new instance of the map is created every time it's called. Which means that `patient->getDrugs().begin()` and `patient->getDrugs().end()` don't form a valid range over the same container - they come from different containers. And moreover, they are dangling iterators - the actual container is destroyed before the iterator can be used.

Comment: Yes it does. But if I change the RV to be by referrence, it has to be

 `const map<string, Drug *>& Patient::getDrugs() const
{
 return this->drugs;
}`

and in that case, I won't be able to change it (add, remove elements to the map, etc.), do I?


(`Patient` is the name of the class this function belongs to)

Comment: Why does it have to be so? You could return by non-const reference.